# Vuejs changes focus after updating property

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have text area which's value is binded to `input` and event `signalChange` on `keydown`

and I'd want to do something like:

if user types `@` then add `()` after that `@` and focus other element

so,

`abc @` changes to `abc @()` and `focus #test`

```
signalChange(evt) 
{
    let target = evt.target;
    let text = evt.target.value;
    let start = evt.target.selectionStart;
    let end = evt.target.selectionEnd;
    let key = evt.key;

    if (key == "@")
    {
        this.input = target.value.slice(0, start) + "()" + target.value.slice(start);       
        evt.preventDefault();
        document.GetElementById("test").focus();
    }
}
```

but the problem is that this textarea is still having focus on itself, but when I change `this.input` to `target.value`, then everything is ok

so apparently problem is with with vue?

Comment: Is `signalChange` a method of a vue instance?

Comment: Is `document.GetElementById("test").focus();` literally what's in your code? Because GetElementById should be **getElementById**